# What's the best method to free memory?

Tags: c, malloc, free, calloc

I'm working on ANSI C.

I have a string object which created with array of char..
I think the object make a memory leak..
when I run my program about five minutes (maybe almost 10000 iteration) my used memory become bigger and bigger..

I tried to free my object used memory with free and delete function. but, delete isn't a valid function. in the other side, free looks like running well first. but I got `free():invalid pointer`..

How can I fix this? I can do it differently?

---

here's a little of my code..

```
char *ext;
ext = calloc(20, sizeof(char));
//do something with ext
free(ext);
```

Comment: `free` is the right function. If you're getting `invalid pointer` errors, it means you have a bug in your code. Please post the relevant parts.

Comment: No code, no cookie.

Comment: that's a little of my code..
I make a new char * at the first time when I call my function, and I free at the end of my function...
I can't copy all of my program to this forum, because it's long enough.. >,<

Comment: @Bobby, that looks alright, but what is happening in the `//do something with ext`, is it being written to, did you accdently do `ext = /*some value*/` ?

Comment: what I do in //do something with ext are some `strcpy(ext, "something");`, `strcat(othervar, ext);`, and `ext[0]='a';`
did I do something wrong?

Comment: @Bobby, post the actual code and we can look at it properly.

Comment: No, those operations are fine. The potential problem Node mentioned was that you allocate memory for 'ext' but then modify 'ext' itself and at the end you 'free' some pointer which is not 'ext' (like 'ext++', for instance)

Comment: -1 the bug is in the code that only you can see; if you don't show us the code then you'll have to solve it yourself

Answer (score 1):

In C, you allocated memory on the heap with `malloc`, and release is with `free`.  So you are correct there.  `delete` is used in C++, and then, only if the memory was allocated with the `new` operator.

If you are getting an invalid pointer error in your call to `free`, then there is likely a bug somewhere in the code, if you post it we could take a look at it.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you're writing past the end of the allocated memory. With

```
calloc(20, sizeof(char))
```

you allocate space for 20 characters (19 "regular" and a null terminator for strings).

Make **very** sure none of your `strcat()` try to write "regular" characters beyond `str[18]`.

Answer (score 0):

Without more code:

1. An array in memory just prior to what ext points to overran its storage and corrupted a type of "header" that malloc() uses to track the size of the memory for subsequent calls to free() (think of ((size_t *)ext)[-1] holding the size from the malloc).

   You used a negative array index into ext[negative] that did the same corruption.

   ext somehow gets modified.